# How to use state in a React/Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to write an office add-in using Office-JS. There is a Yeoman generator that creates boilerplate components and directories. The syntax is quite different from what I'm used to, and I'm unable to create a state for the main component.

The file `App.tsx` came with 2 interfaces and one class:

```
export interface AppProps {
    title: string;
    isOfficeInitialized: boolean;
}

export interface AppState {
}

export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }
    render() {
      <div>
        <Body message='Click on the button below to apply formatting' buttonLabel='Format' click={ this.format_workbook } />
      </div>
    }
```

It also came with a `Content.tsx` file which I re purposed to `Body.tsx`. It contains one interface and one component:

```
export interface ContentProps {
    message: string;
    buttonLabel: string;
    click: any;
}

export class Body extends React.Component<ContentProps, any> {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
      ...
    }
}
```

What I need to do now, is pass a state-controlled array to `Body`, like so (on `App`'s `render()`):

```
<Body message='Click on the button below to apply formatting.' buttonLabel='Format' click={ this.format_workbook } console={this.state.messages} />
```

I have tried:

on App's constructor:

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.setState({
    messages: [],
  })
// alternatively:
  this.state = { messages: [] }
}
```

on `AppState`:

```
export interface AppState {
  messages: string[];
}
```

and on `ContentProps` (in `Body`):

```
export interface ContentProps {
    message: string;
    buttonLabel: string;
    click: any;
    console: string[];
}
```

And variations of these changes. However, regardless of what I do, I get compilation errors that look like:

```
TS2322: Type '{ message: string; buttonLabel: string; click: () => Promise<void>; messages: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Body> & Readonly<ContentProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'messages' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Body> & Readonly<ContentProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I can create a state for components in this context?

Comment: The error says that `ContentProps` doesn't have a `messages` property.

Comment: Which confuses me, because I'm passing `messages` to `Body` through a prop called `console`, so `ContentProps` should have a `console` attribute. Am I understanding this right?